# How to set up a FCM app server alongside a website to send push notifications?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications to my app's users. I have found [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) tutorial by the Firebase team and read the documentation, in particular the one about the [server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server).

It seems fairly simply but I am struggling with where I need to put Node.js code as it is not something I have done before. I currently have a website complete with index.html, style.css, etc. Where should I be putting the JavaScript code in order to make it run? If I simply create a file called Node.js at the root of my web server will that be enough to do the tutorial I linked earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a host that will allow you to run node.js scripts. Node that typical web hosts, such as Firebase Hosting, will not allow you to run node.js scripts. So you'll typically have a separate web site (which you can run almost anywhere) and a node host, which allows you to run node.js scripts on *their* server.

The blog post you refer to has a link to [running node.js on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/), which is one of the many platform that can run node.js scripts for you.

Since recommending a specific platform is off-topic on StackOverflow, the next best thing is a search like https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=Where+can+I+run+node.js+scripts.